# how to change into rule (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I'm currently learning about Prolog and doesn't quite understand how to turn this statement into a rule. this one particular question confuse me a lot. please help!

this is the database:

```
weather(tuesday,fair).
weather(wednesday,overcast).
weather(thursday,overcast).
weather(friday,rainy).
weather(saturday,overcast).

color_of_the_sky(blue,Day) :- weather(Day,fair).
color_of_the_sky(grey,Day) :- weather(Day,overcast).

status(active,sunday).
status(active,tuesday).
status(active,thursday).

happy(Day) :- weather(Day,fair), status(active,Day).
```

the statement is:

> birds will have mixed feeling when it is raining and birds are active.

Comment: It's a poorly constructed homework assignment.  Birds are not defined anywhere and mixed feeling is not mentioned anywhere.  No wonder you are confused.  The instructor ought to use facts and rules with descriptive names.  In my opinion none of the above are properly descriptive.  I believe the last rule is intended to say "birds are happy when the weather is fair and birds are active."

Comment: `mixed(Day) :- weather(Day, rainy), status(active, Day).`

Comment: The key here is to understand Prolog syntax is to read `:-` as "if", and say about the left side, "I can conclude". So, "I can conclude `happy(Day)` if `weather(Day, fair)` and `status(active, Day)`.

Comment: ohhhh i see ! thank you very muchh! the birds confuse me so much thanksss